# How to test method with URL as parameter which produces a json using mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I am passing a service url which will fetch a json. I am mapping the json to response class using object mapper. How will i mock the url to invoke the actual service in test case?

```
public String QUOTE_SUMMARY_URL = "http://localhost:8181/omnesys_sb/quote";

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public Quotesummary getQuoteSummary(final String urlString) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    String line, jsonString = null;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String urlStr = urlString != null ? urlString : QUOTE_SUMMARY_URL;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line + '\n');
        }
        jsonString = stringBuilder.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e)   {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e)   {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    }
    Quotesummary quoteSummary = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Quotesummary.class);
    System.out.println(""+mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(quoteSummary));
    return quoteSummary;
}
```

Comment: As this seems to be a way to manually call a REST service: Have you considered using a better framework than just do everything the hard way? Spring's RestTemplate, for example, would allow you to easily test your json request against a mocked server... (Besides making the code for the whole request much cleaner).